# how to match a given 2d-matrix to submatrix of another 2d-matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

lets say there are two matrices A and B.
I want to find the starting index of submatrix of B which is equivalent to matrix A.
for eg-

```
matrix A=>  8 2
            3 4

matrix B=> 1 2 6
           9 8 2
           1 3 4
```

answer is- position matrixB[2][2]

Comment: and what exactly stops you here? You do not know how to write a double loop?

Answer (score 1):

1. Scan matrix B using a double loop. Limit the search to the top left rectangle defined by the difference of the sizes.
2. Check whether the corresponding areas match A using another double loop. If they fully match, you are done; otherwise, continue with 1.

Pseudocode:

```
// Helper 
bool checkMatch(int by, int bx) {
  for (int ay = 0; ay < ah; ay++) {
    for (int ax = 0; ax < aw; ax++) {
      if (a[ay][ax] != b[by + ay][bx + ax]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Scan loop
for (int by = 0; by < bh - ah; by++) {
  for (int bx = 0; bx < bw - aw; bx++) {
    if (checkMatch(by, bx)) {
      println("Found: " + bx + " + by);
      // stop here if one occurence is enough
    }
  }
}
```